# Why is firebase function only fetching once?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase

I have a firebase fetch function which I call inside of a for loop. In it, I pass in variables postID and uid.

```
           for child in snapshots.reversed() {

                let keyValue = child.key
                let uid = keyValue.split(separator: ":")[0]
                let postIDDoubleVal = keyValue.split(separator: ":")[1]
                print(String(uid), " This is the uid!!!!!!")
                print(postIDDoubleVal, " This is tfdsafdsafdsafdsafads4!!!!")

                self.fetchUsersPost(uid: String(uid), postID: "post:\(postIDDoubleVal)")
            }
```

There are currently 2 users who's UIDs ARE successfully looped over.

The problem arrises when calling the function `fetchUsersPost`. For some reason for one of the loops (I believe the second) it works properly, but for the first it does not.

The beginning of the fetch function is:

```
    func fetchUsersPost(uid: String, postID: String) {
    print("fetchUsersPost Posts/\(uid)/\(postID)")
```

Here is the output:

```
    fetchUsersPost Posts/QUocyvGehdeaOO9vVnklwOrWH7l1/post:580077760
 QUocyvGehdeaOO9vVnklwOrWH7l1  This is the uid!!!!!!
580077723  This is tfdsafdsafdsafdsafads4!!!!
fetchUsersPost Posts/ QUocyvGehdeaOO9vVnklwOrWH7l1/post:580077723
```

I wonder if the problem is related to the fact that on one of the print statements (the second) there is a space between the uid and the '/'

**What is the problem?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have 1 user with `UID = QUocyvGehdeaOO9vVnklwOrWH7l1` who has 2 posts with `580077760` and `580077723` , if there is a space you need to verify that you create the child key correctly when you set the value for it

```
let keyValue = child.key
```

as `UID:POSTID` with no leading , trailing or middle spaces , also make sure whether these 2 posts have a valid value before you fetch them